# How to hide the page number in LaTex on first page of a chapter?

Tags: latex

How to hide the page number on first page of a chapter in LaTeX.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

```
\thispagestyle{empty}
```

Comment: Doesn't work for all cases.

Comment: could you be more specific?

Comment: think of a page with an image at the top and then a pagebreak. If you put only \thispagestyle once, it doesn't work. I had to put it also before pagebreak.

Answer (score 2):

You could also use the titlesec package to get tremendous control over each chapter:

```
  % This is done with the titlesec package                                                                            
  \titleformat{\chapter}[display]
              {\normalfont\Large\filcenter} % {fmt}                                                                   
              {\thechapter.\ }              % {label}                                                                 
              {1pc}                         % {sep}                                                                   
              {\vspace{-1in}\enlargethispage{-0.5in}\thispagestyle{empty}}    % {before}
```